# Variation of $x\to \tan x$ over $(\pi/2,\pi ]$ without using derivation?

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry, monotone-functions

I'm sorry to ask this trivial question, i have accrossed this problem with my students of high school level , they are not discussed "Derivation method" to set the monotonicity of any real valued function . The main problem is if i assume that : there are two real :$x_1,x_2\in (\pi/2,\pi]$ such that $x_1>x_2$ then we have : $$\sin x_1<\sin x_2\tag{1}$$ , and $$\cos x_1<\cos x_2\tag{2}$$ .

The two function are decreasing in $(\pi/2,\pi]$, The problem it's not allowed to divide the inequality $(1)$ over inequality $(2)$ ., then how do i can get the variation of  $x\to \tan x$ using this method or any simple method for this level without derivation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that

$$\sin x>0 \quad \sin x_1<\sin x_2\iff \frac{\sin x_1}{\sin x_2}<1$$

$$\cos x<0 \quad \cos x_1<\cos x_2\iff \frac{\cos x_2}{\cos x_1}<1$$

then since $\tan x<0$

$$\frac{\sin x_1}{\sin x_2}\frac{\cos x_2}{\cos x_1}=\frac{\tan x_1}{\tan x_2}<1\implies \tan x_1>\tan x_2$$

Comment: Gimusi. Very nice.

Comment: How this les than 1 : $\frac{\tan x_1}{\tan x_2}<1$ ?

Comment: Since $0<\frac{\sin x_1}{\sin x_2}<1$ and $0<\frac{\cos x_2}{\cos x_1}<1$ then $0<\frac{\sin x_1}{\sin x_2}\frac{\cos x_2}{\cos x_1}<1$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** It might be easier to show that $\tan(x)$ is increasing on $\left[0,\frac\pi2\right)$, then use $\tan(x)=-\tan(\pi-x)$

Answer (score 0):

You have $$sin x_1<sin x_2\tag{1}$$ and $$cos x_1<cos x_2\tag{2}$$ Upon multiplying  both sides of $ (2)$ by  $-1$ we get $$ -cos x_1>-cos x_2\tag{3}$$ At this point let us compare $ \frac {sin x_1}{-cos x_1}$ with $ \frac {sin x_2}{-cos x_2}$.

Note that for $ x_1,x_2\in (\pi/2,\pi]$ , $ sinx_1< sinx_2$ and $ -cos x_1>-cos x_2 $.

Therefore, $-tanx_1<-tanx_2$ which is  equivalent to  $tanx_1>tanx_2$.

Thus $tan(x)$ is increasing on the given interval.